# specific select option array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm coding about select options. i want to select to local option after select localModel and than It should be shown.
I'm success through array but, I'don't know receive array to text.

Received Data after Selected local1, local2

**Q1=local1&Q2=1**

> if selected local1, shown town1, town2, town3 about selecting local1
>
> if selected local2, shown town1, town2, town3 about selecting local2

```js
var localsAndModels = {};
localsAndModels['local1'] = ['town1', 'town2', 'town3'];
localsAndModels['local2'] = ['town1', 'town2', 'town3', 'town4'];
localsAndModels['local3'] = ['town1', 'town2', 'town3'];

function ChangeLocalList() {

  var localList = document.getElementById("local");
  var modelList = document.getElementById("localmodel");
  var selLocal = localList.options[localList.selectedIndex].value;

  while (modelList.options.length) {
    modelList.remove(0);
  }
  var locals = localsAndModels[selLocal];
  if (locals) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < locals.length; i++) {
      var local = new Option(locals[i], i);
      modelList.options.add(local);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="searchTown.do">
    <select class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" name="Q0" id="local" onchange="ChangeLocalList()">
     <option value="">--select local--</option>
     <option value="local1">local1</option>
     <option value="local2">local2</option>
     <option value="local3">local3</option>
     
    </select>
    <select class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" name="Q1" id="localmodel">
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that you get the numeric value of 0, 1 instead of town1, town2 ? You are building the Option by specifying the index. Change it to use the same as the text. `var local = new Option(locals[i], locals[i]);` If this is not what you meant to ask, can you please elaborate on what is the exact question ?

Comment: no problem jsp page. but if select option, if not the text,
The array is being received as the [ i ] th numeric.

i have got receive only text value.

Comment: http://localhost:8081/SpringWebPrj/searchTown.do?Q0=%EC%84%9C%EC%9A%B8%ED%8A%B9%EB%B3%84%EC%8B%9C&Q1=0&ORD=Addr

please look at the Q1=0 this is localmodel data. i don't need numeric 
Q1 = 0 is not a number, but should be received as String data called town1.

Comment: OK but have you tried changing the code as I mentioned? in your code in the for loop you need to put `var local = new Option(locals[i], locals[i]);`

Comment: the answer is late.
successfully!! thank a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the numeric value since you set the option as such. Replace it to pass in the same text and it should work the way you want it to.
[Html Option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)

`var local = new Option(locals[i], locals[i]);`